# Pegar array completo com AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs

Template

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="item.title" list="comicstitle">
  <datalist id="comicstitle">
    <option  data-ng-repeat="ttl in titles" value="{{ttl.name}}">
  </datalist>
```

js

```
$rootScope.titles = [{"id":"1","name":"Alface","value":"1.00"},{"id":"3","name":"Bacon","value":"2.00"},{"id":"4","name":"Queijo Cheedar","value":"2.00"},{"id":"5","name":"Mostarda Dijon","value":"2.00"}];
```

Preciso que ao buscar o item preencha um `input` com os dados do array

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<input type="text" ng-model="id">
<input type="text" ng-model="value">
```

Comment: Por um acaso é isto que você está procurando? http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/g2oc1mmn/

Comment: Diego isso mesmo muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta fazer da seguinte forma

***HTML***

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.title" list="comicstitle" />
    <select id="comicstitle" ng-model="item.titles">
        <option  value="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="ttl in titles"> {{ttl.name}} </option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" ng-model="titles[item.titles].name" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="titles[item.titles].id" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="titles[item.titles].value" />
</div>
```

Implemente a sua solução.

**[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/g2oc1mmn/)**